# DAX Trying to create a measure that filters a Country by Continent

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a 'Countries table', in this table there are two columns. 'Continent' and 'Country'.

I want to create a measure filters the 'Countries' of the 'Continents' Europe and Africa.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please share 3 rows of sample data and expected results. What do you want to achieve? What you do, and what you get and how is it different of what you want?

Comment: I want a measure which returns all the countries that are in Europe and Africa only from the 'Countries' table.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dax/filter-function-dax

```
Fitered Table =
FILTER (
    'Countries table',
    'Countries table'[Continent] IN { "Europe", "Africa" }
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I have tried using this and been through the docs, it gives mes an error saying the expressions refers to multiple columns. in the formula above, where would i return the filtered column of 'Countries'[Country]

Comment: Sure, it's a table expression, so you have to put it into the "New table" UI, not "New Measure" nor "New Column".